# Simulating image "lightness" in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have some images on top of each other and I want to create a fading out effect for the ones behind.

However, opacity doesn't do the trick because you can see through the image behind it.
A brightness filter doesn't work for me either because in addition to lightness it also increases saturation.

Essentially what I want is a white underlay or overlay for each image, combined with an opacity change for either the image or the overlay. I'm thinking this has a pseudoelement solution but I'm not confident I can get the positioning done correctly.

[image]

Here is a working example:

```css
.spread-content {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
}
 .spread-content .spread-img {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     height: 25rem;
     justify-content: center;
     margin: 4rem 15rem 2rem 15rem;
     flex-shrink: 1;
}
 .spread-content .spread-img .img {
     position: absolute;
     transform: rotate(-8deg) translate(-15, 8%);
     transition: all 1s ease;
     width: 40vw;
     max-width: 15rem;
     filter: drop-shadow(0 2rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}
 .spread-content .spread-img:hover > #img-1 {
     transform: rotate(2deg) translateX(15%);
}
 .spread-content .spread-img:hover > #img-2 {
     transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0%, 4%);
     opacity: 0.7;
}
 .spread-content .spread-img:hover > #img-3 {
     transform: rotate(-8deg) translate(-15%, 8%);
     opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="spread-content">
  <div class="spread-img">
    <img id="img-3" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    <img id="img-2" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    <img id="img-1" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to obtain this using a pseudo-element, as pseudo elements get rendered *inside* their master. So any change in opacity will also impact any pseudo-element within your `<img>`.

Best solution is to wrap them in a box, that will have a white background and fit them automatically.

I took the liberty to correct a few lines that seemed to have typos or misplaced CSS, and chose to have a fixed height for images.

I also changed your `filter: drop-shadow` to a `box-shadow` that looks a lot smoother:

```css
.spread-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.spread-content .spread-img {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 25rem;
  width: 40vw;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 4rem 15rem 2rem 15rem;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.spread-content .spread-img .img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-8deg) translate(-15%, 8%);
  max-width: 15rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.spread-content .spread-img img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.spread-content .spread-img:hover #img-1 {
  transform: rotate(2deg) translateX(15%);
}

.spread-content .spread-img:hover #img-2 {
  transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0%, 4%);
}

.spread-content .spread-img:hover #img-2 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.spread-content .spread-img:hover #img-3 {
  transform: rotate(-8deg) translate(-15%, 8%);
}

.spread-content .spread-img:hover #img-3 img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="spread-content">
  <div class="spread-img">
    <div class="img" id="img-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="img" id="img-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="img" id="img-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*The `transform` rule in your `.spread-content .spread-img .img` selector missed a unit in `translate` function, so it was not rendered. Hence the different start orientation of cards*

Comment: Amazing stuff!! Also great catch on the missing unit, I was wondering why that wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

> A brightness filter doesn't work for me either because in addition to lightness it also increases saturation.

You can de-saturate image first and increase brightness after that.  Using   `contrast(<below 100%>)` or `invert(<below 50%>)` before `brightness()` have effect similar to semi-transparent white overlay:

```css
p { background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; height: 5em; padding: 0 1em 0 4em; float: left; border: solid; margin: .1em; position: relative; max-width: 7em;  }
p::before { content: attr(style); }
p[style="/*overlay*/"]::after { content:''; position: absolute; inset: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5)}
```

```html
<p style="/*original*/">
<p style="filter: brightness(150%)">
<p style="/*overlay*/">
<p style="filter: contrast(30%)">
<p style="filter: contrast(30%) brightness(150%)">
<p style="filter: invert(35%) brightness(150%)">
```

Applied to your code:

```css
.spread-content {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
}
 .spread-content .spread-img {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     height: 25rem;
     justify-content: center;
     margin: 4rem 15rem 2rem 15rem;
     flex-shrink: 1;
}
 .spread-content .spread-img .img {
     position: absolute;
     transition: all 1s ease;
     width: 40vw;
     max-width: 15rem;
     transform: rotate(-8deg) translate(-15%, 8%);
     filter: invert(0%) brightness(100%) drop-shadow(0 2rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}
 .spread-content .spread-img:hover > #img-1 {
     transform: rotate(2deg) translateX(15%);
}
 .spread-content .spread-img:hover > #img-2 {
     transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0%, 4%);
     filter: invert(20%) brightness(120%) drop-shadow(0 2rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}
 .spread-content .spread-img:hover > #img-3 {
     transform: rotate(-8deg) translate(-15%, 8%);
     filter: invert(30%) brightness(130%) drop-shadow(0 2rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}
```

```html
<div class="spread-content">
  <div class="spread-img">
    <img id="img-3" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    <img id="img-2" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    <img id="img-1" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Cool to know a combination of filters can be used to achieve the same effect. I imagine it would be a fair bit of trial and error though to accurately reproduce different levels of lightness.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using one element and less of code. You can easily adjust the image by changing one variable:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  margin:20px auto;
  position:relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  transition:0.5s;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fffc,transparent) bottom/100% 1000%,
    var(--img) center/cover;
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  transition:0.5s;
  transform-origin:inherit;
  background: var(--img) center/cover;
}
.box::before {
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff9,transparent) bottom/100% 1000%,
    var(--img) center/cover;
}

.box:hover {
  transform:translateY(4%) rotate(-15deg);
  background-position:top,center;
}
.box:hover:before {
  transform:translateY(-3%) rotate(8deg);
  background-position:top,center;
}
.box:hover:after {
  transform:translateY(-5%) rotate(15deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80)"> </div>
```

Comment: This is genius, totally didn't think to use multiple background functions. It also seems to be more performant? And it doesn't have any white edges that are produced from an overlay solution.

Comment: @asa9ohan it depends on what you mean by *performant* but it's at least minimalistic and easy to adjust without duplicating the image.